# How do I turn this js speech recognition code into a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

I have three input boxed for js speech recognition to gather user speech from, conduct speech recognition, and then append to the input form. I am lost how to simply use a for loop to accomplish this. I've looked all over stackoverflow, reddit, youtube, and basic google but still do not understand. Any advice and or help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
<div class="container" id="therapist_container">
            <div id="button">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="record()" id="therapist-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Talk with Delphi</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="vid1Title" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <video width="100%" id="video1">
                      <source src="./static/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    <form class="texts" action="/care" id="careid" name="care" method="POST">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="what's your name?">
                      <input type="text1" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Where are you?">
                      <input type="text1" id="state" name="state" placeholder="how can I help?">
                      <input id="buttonInput" class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
              $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                  $('#video1')[0].play();
                })
              $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                  $('#video1')[0].pause();
                })

              video = document.getElementById('video1');
              
              function record() {
                var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || SpeechRecognition();
                recognition.interimResults = true;
                recognition.lang = "en-US";

                recognition.start();
 
                recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                  console.log(event);
                  document.getElementById("name").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                }
              
                recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                  recognition.start();
                  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById("location").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                  }
                })

                recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                  recognition.start();
                  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById("state").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                  }
                })

                // recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                //     recognition.start();
                //     recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                //       document.getElementById("state").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                //   }
                
                //   // recognition.addEventListener("end", () => {
                //   //   window.location.pathname = '/care';
                //   //   document.care.submit();
                //   // });
                // })
              }  
            </script>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expected ?

```
recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
 const boxes = [ "location", "state"];
 for( var box in boxes ) {
    recognition.start();
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
      document.getElementById(box).value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: why use box in boxes? should it be for text?

Comment: yeah, that's just the variable name to change the value of the parameter in `getElementById(<box>)`, that's the only thing that I noticed was different in your functions, although my answer is a guess because I don't know how the whole thing is working

Comment: yeah I tried that and unfortunately, it wasn't wotking...